# Measuring Performance of Dalvik

Tags: android, performance, dalvik

I've been reading up on the android dalvik and I was wondering if there are any applications that measure the performance of the dalvik? If there aren't, based on what aspects could one develop an app to measure the performance of the dalvik?

I know that this is a website for Programming questions, but I didnt know where else to ask this question. If this is not a valid question, I would appreciate it if someone could direct me to a place where I could ask this.

Thanks!

Comment: try this [PerfMon - Performance Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.perfmon&feature=search_result)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "canned" solution, there are various benchmarks available [on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dalvik+benchmark).  Many of them upload results to web sites where you can compare your results against those from other devices.

If you're interested in writing your own benchmarks, the [Caliper benchmark framework](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/CaliperOnAndroid) may be useful.

As to where else to ask this question, the [Android Enthusiasts stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) might be more appropriate.